# Crash when displaying / rasterizing graphics with textures at high resolutions

Tags: graphics, textures, crash, hardware

**CAUTION/Disclaimer: execution of some of the code below can result in a complete crash of Mathematica or even your system. Save all your work and do not try in a productive situation.**

For a graphical application, I need to export graphics containing several hi-res textures at large image sizes.

Consider the following (minimal example) code wich is largely harmless:

```
Graphics[{Texture[Graphics[Circle[]]], 
  Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
 ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

**But** upping `ImageSize` past a given (probably hardware-dependent, in my case ~4000) threshold will crash the frontend+kernel

```
Graphics[{Texture[Graphics[Circle[]]], 
  Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
 ImageSize -> 4000]
```

To make things worse, this also seems to depend on the graphics driver version. I use a NVIDIA GTX 485M card, and with the 296.10 driver, I can go up to about `ImageSize -> 8000` while with any *newer* driver version the system stalls at `ImageSize -> 4000`.

Does anyone know a workaround? Always reverting to an obsolete driver (which e.g. does not work with `CUDALink` anymore) is not optimal.

**Addendum: Question, Part Two**

As pointed out by @cormullion, setting the global preferences for the antialiasing quality in the Preferences dialog helps already a lot and allows much larger `ImagesSize`s.

Now, how to go about setting/resetting the value of `HardwareAntialiasingQuality` programmatically?

Comment: What's your Antialiasing preference set to? I had more frequent crashes with this set to medium or high, but far fewer when set to lowest.

Comment: @cormullion Cool - setting  Antialiasing to None in the Preferences dialog helps working with much larger sizes. Please consider an answer.

Comment: Since you were the last to pipe up on meta, I'm using your question as a guinea pig to test out the new close options =) Brace yourself for a close storm and/or additional comments :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had problems when pushing images above a certain size. For example, it's ok at 1500:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", ImageSize -> 1500]
```

[image: ok plot]

But pushing it too far:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", ImageSize -> 2000]
```

[image: not ok plot]

While I quite like the effect, in an artistic kind of way, clearly Mathematica is reaching into regions of the computer's memory that it shouldn't be. I can see glimpses of other apps, previously opened documents, and so on. (This was a fresh kernel.)

I've had this on versions 8 and 9, and was about to conclude that my computer was going wrong. However, on a hunch, I reset the Antialiasing prefs from Highest down to No Antialiasing, and now the problem doesn't occur very often.

[image: prefs]

I must have set it to High for some reason, and forgot that larger images would probably stress it too much.

Your problem may be related!

Comment: What would be the most convenient way to locally turn off antialiasing without resorting to the preferences menu?

Comment: @yves FrontEnd Options contains "RenderingOptions -> {"HardwareAntialiasingQuality" -> 0.}", perhaps you can explore that?

Comment: Correct - I just cannot remember the correct way to set that option (if I ever knew that firstplace). Thought it was around, but cannot find it.

Comment: What OS do you see this happen on ?

Comment: @rcollyer I'm on Mac

Comment: What version of the OS? Can you email it to me, plus what hardware your running on? (robertc at everyone's favorite company) I'm not able to reproduce it on my mac running 10.8.2.

Comment: Let me rephrase: I don't get the images from other software, instead I just get a black image once I go above a reasonable threshold in `ImageSize`.

Comment: @rcollyer I'm on 2.7GHz Intel Core i5, iMac, running 10.8.2. I've sent artistic pictures by email...

Comment: Weird. On my Windows machine, I can draw with ImageSize->10000 and highest graphics quality, no problem. Maybe anti-aliased drawing is done by the OS and OSX can't draw to surfaces bigger than the screen resolution?

Comment: @nikie Judging from some of the questions here, there's an interesting comparison between Windows-only problems and Mac OSX-only problems (not to mention Linux-only problems). Must be hard to write 100% platform-independent code...