# Is there a way to programmatically set global preferences?

Tags: graphics, front-end, graphics3d, output-formatting, options

Can I set global preferences that are accessible via "Edit"->"Preferences" programmatically from within a notebook?

As learned from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18996/131), turning off anti-aliasing can make a huge difference in the maximum allowable `ImageSize`. This can be done via menu:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The slider is setting the value of `HardwareAntialiasingQuality` that can be found with the option inspector:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Question: Is there a way to set/reset the value of `HardwareAntialiasing` (and others) programmatically? I´d like to set this with a line only in those notebooks that benefit from this setting and have proper antialiasing for the rest.

Footnote: this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/190/131) does help with setting the rendering method directly within a `Graphics3D` expression, and as @Sjoerd's answer shows this also works in more global way.

Comment: I'm also curious about how to set it back to the default value programatically (what that little green X does in your screenshot).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe the following should work:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, RenderingOptions -> {"HardwareAntialiasingQuality" -> 1}]
```

for a permanent global setting,

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, RenderingOptions -> {"HardwareAntialiasingQuality" -> 1}]
```

for a temporary (session duration) global setting, and

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], RenderingOptions -> {"HardwareAntialiasingQuality" -> 1}]
```

in each notebook for which you want an individualized setting.

Comment: Spot on! Works nicely - and for the other options as well. I  am looking forward to any answers topping that :-)

Comment: @YvesKlett Glad to be of service.

Comment: Maybe it's good to note that CurrentValue works as well.  It is advantageous to use `CurrentValue` when there are sub options to an option (like `a -> {b -> 1, c -> 2}`) because it makes it easy to set one sub option without touching the rest.

Comment: @Szabolcs good one. Why not post an answer on that? Might be quite useful  in days to come.

Comment: Perhaps you can also mention `$FrontEndSession` for completeness...

Comment: @rm-rf Good one. Added.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries You might even mention the mythical $DefaulFrontEnd, taught to us by Director Futz [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7747454#7747454)

Comment: @RolfMertig Nice! This probably answers Szabolcs' question about the little green cross. I wonder whether you should only read this option, not write.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of `SetOptions`, it is also possible to use `CurrentValue`. In this particular case the syntax is

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {RenderingOptions, "HardwareAntialiasingQuality"}] = 1.0
```

`CurrentValue` is easier to use than `SetOptions` in the situation when a single option has multiple sub options.  If we have an option of the form `opt -> {a -> 1, b -> 2}`, then `SetOptions[..., opt -> {a -> 1}]` would remove the sub-option `b`.  (This is not the case with `RenderingOptions`, but it is with others, e.g. "`PalettesMenuSettings"` or `TaggingRules`, which can have completely arbitrary sub options.)  The simplest solution in this situation is `CurrentValue[object, {opt, a}] = ...`.  This will not touch the suboption `b`.

Comment: @Scabolcs +1 Also: sometimes SetOptions just does not work. E.g. SetOptions[Cell,CellEpilog->somefun] gives a strange message, while CurrentValue is acting just fine.

Comment: But note what John Fultz has to say about problems with `CurrentValue` and `$DefaultFrontEnd` [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7747441#7747441).

Comment: @Sjoerd Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't know.