# how to make cursor jump automatically to next input cell after evaluating previous one?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells

When making separate cells in order to make separate computations to better see the result of each one before going to the next cell to do the next computation (which is a good way of doing things), it will be very useful and more efficient if the cursor would jump to the start of next input cell automatically.

This allows one to keep the hand on the `ENTER` key, and just hit `ENTER` again, without having to reach to the `downarrow` key to reposition the cursor to the next cell, and move the hand again to the `ENTER` key. This can get tiring if one has many cells to process one by one. (This is btw how Maple does it, it automatically jumps to start of next command)

Here is an example

[image]

Is it possible to make the notebook do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can setup `CellEpilog` to automatically advance a cell after evaluating the current one. That way, you don't need to press the down arrow after evaluating a cell.

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
    CellEpilog :> SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, Cell]]
```

Comment: [You beat me to it!](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29258/how-to-fold-output-cells-by-default/29393#comment91609_29258) (By only seven odd hours :o) +1

Comment: @rm-rf Is there any way to evaluate the next cell automatically without the need to press ENTER?

Comment: @M6299 Why don't you do `Evaluate Notebook` from the menu then?

Comment: @rm-rf Because I want to evaluate only some of the cells and I use `SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, Cell]]` at the end of these cells.

Comment: Is there a way to make this option 'permanent'? Currently, I have to find and evaluate that code every time I make a new notebook.

Comment: @JonWarneke I believe you can replace `EvaluationNotebook[]` with `$FrontEnd` to make it permanent. See [https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19441/45091](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19441/45091).

Answer (score 17):

If your keyboard has a numeric keypad, or a way to emulate one by using a function key, you can use Shift+Enter on the numeric keypad.  This keystroke will evaluate a cell if you're in an evaluatable cell, or move to the next evaluatable cell if you're not.  It would still be two keystrokes to move then evaluate, but it'd be the same keystroke.

Comment: That is the reason why I always look for notebook keyboards with an Enter key...

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I prefer `CellProlog` instead of `CellEpilog` like in [rm -rf's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29399/85050).
This has the benefit of jumping to the next cell before the cell is evaluated. This avoids getting kicked out of a cell when a slow cell finishes. It does however not work on a cell if you are currently running another cell.

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellProlog :> SelectionMove[NextCell[CellStyle -> "Input"], All, Cell]]
```