# How can I prevent SHIFT-ENTER moving the editing cursor?

Tags: front-end, wolfram-cloud

What I do: Here

[image]

press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to evaluate.

What I get: The cursor disappeared

[image]

What I want: The cursor retained

[image]

Workaround: Up Arrow as many times as it takes, Right arrow as many times as it takes.

Note: Related may be the fact that on Windows Chrome, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> hides the cursor :(

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that. But instead of right arrowing, why not just up arrow until you're under the input cell, and then do one left arrow. This takes you to the end of the cell immediately Often that's only three keystrokes.

Comment: closely related: [29396](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29396/5478) @community: Close enough to be a duplicate?

Comment: @Kuba in this case, I don't think so. The FE and cloud are sufficiently different that i don't think they're duplicates.

Comment: If this question is about the programming cloud, please mention is specifically within the body of the post.  Do not rely on tags to convey information (at least not in Mma.SE)

Comment: @rcollyer sure, I agree, I have missed WPC reference.

Answer (score 13):

Is this what you are after?

```
SetOptions[
 EvaluationNotebook[],
 CellEpilog :> (
   SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, EvaluationCell];
   SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, CellContents];
   )
 ]
```

Comment: +1 but based on the tags the OP seems to want to do this in the Programming Cloud, where it doesn't work.

Comment: @Szabolcs oh, right, WPC is off topic, isn't it?

Comment: @Kuba :P but to give a serious answer: This question is specifically about the WPC because it's a question about using the editor, not about the language. WPC is not off-topic per se because this StackExchange exists to discuss Mathematica and related software, and I don't think anyone disputes that the WPC is related to Mathematica.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Sure, if it's about WPC I will delete it. I don't know what's the status, could you point me to source of " this StackExchange exists to discuss Mathematica and related software".

Comment: I wouldn't delete it, it's still a valid answer for the desktop FE.

Comment: @PatrickStevens my understanding is that related software is on-topic if its usage relates to *Mathematica*, not necessarily its genesis. For example, Wolfram|Alpha is based on *Mathematica*, but knowing *Mathematica* does not help one to answer a question about W|A. So, W|A is off-topic here unless the question is about interacting with W|A using *Mathematica*. (Otherwise, we defer to the experts on that particular product, who are at the Wolfram Community site.) I can imagine a similar argument applying to the Cloud, because it is in a state of flux and none of us really knows how it works.

Comment: @Kuba "could you point me to source of " this StackExchange exists to discuss Mathematica and related software"." The source is where you'd expect, surely. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic **What topics can I ask about here?** "Mathematica Stack Exchange is for users of the software Mathematica developed by Wolfram Research, as well as related products like gridMathematica, Wolfram Workbench, Player (Pro), and the CDF Player."

Comment: @ChrisJJ Thanks, I'm always having trouble finding such info about SE sites. And I find confusing that the greeting screen says something more scoped: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @Kuba You're welcome. Re that confusion, you might want to contribute here http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1630/wouldnt-it-be-nice-if-the-question-form-accorded-with-the-forum-scope and http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1636/are-people-working-together-to-build-a-library-of-detailed-answers-to-every-ques

Comment: @ChrisJJ I took a glimpse, the problem is, there is a lot of stuff written there and I don't have time atm to think about this. p.s. I don't think WPC or Cloud should be off topic here but atm they are in beta and the documentation is really the Mathematica documentation and this makes Community or WRI support the only valid places to ask such questions.

Comment: @Kuba FTR, WPC docs differ from Mathematica docs ISTM by IDing some functions that are unavailable in WPC.

Comment: @ChrisJJ From WPC docs one can read about `SelectionMove` and all those FrontEnd procedures that are not yet implemented. WRI stopped taking care about including "cloud" icon which I find highly annoying. It wastes my time to find what works and what is not. I won't answer any question and say it's valid on WPC because IMO there is no official documentation. Even WRI says it's beta.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks. There is official documentation. Just press F1 in WPC IDE. Unfortunately yes is it highly inaccurate and I am beginning to suspect WS are too embarrassed to add the many cloud-bars it truly needs.

Comment: @ChrisJJ The fact the documentation is there is a joke. It is MMA documentation which was at the beginning modified a little to reflect WPC differences, it isn't atm. I had to and you have to accept that they are editing it fully and it is still in beta phase. At the end I had to test each part of code anyway.

Comment: @Kuba "I had to and you have to accept that they are editing it fully". I'll accept that when I see evidence it is true So far I haven't.

Comment: Nice code, but how to actually restore the old cursor position, not just going to the end of the previous cell?

Comment: @kungfooman it is something between this answer and this one: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125032/5478 let me know if you get stuck or I missed your point

Comment: Very nice, is it possible to set this to a keyboard shortcut so that one could use either this or the default shift+ enter? I suppose that would require setting the options using this code, evaluating the cell, and returning to the default options. I am not sure how to evaluate the current cell programmatically.

Comment: @Kuba When one clicks shift+enter on or evaluates a cell, it prevents you from typing/editing it. Pasting in your code and clicking shift+enter to apply your code does not help with it. Do you know how to fix this so typing/editing is not prevented?

Comment: @TymaGaidash What do you mean by that? Prevents from editing even before that code is used? Are you using desktop Mathematica or something else? Which version?