# Wolfram Cloud does not evaluate cells using Shift+Enter

Tags: evaluation, wolfram-cloud, keyboard

When one clicks <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on or evaluates a cell, it prevents you from typing/editing it, so it was thought

> [How can I prevent SHIFT-ENTER moving the editing cursor?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89532/how-can-i-prevent-shift-enter-moving-the-editing-cursor/89534#comment740470_89534)

would stop this, but it did not. Then, a link in a comment below its answer was tested from

> [Make cursor stay in input cell](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125032/85399).

The referenced code evaluated was

```
 With[
  { nb := EvaluationNotebook[]
  , c := EvaluationCell[]
  }
, With[
    { cv := CurrentValue[nb, {"TaggingRules", "LastCursorPosition"}]
    , pos := FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`UndocumentedGetSelectionPacket[nb]
    }
  , With[
      { savePosition := (
          cv = If[MemberQ[pos, "CharacterRange" -> _], Last["CharacterRange" /. pos], False]
        )
      }
    , SetOptions[nb
      , CellEventActions :> {
          {"MenuCommand", "HandleShiftReturn"} :> savePosition
        , {"MenuCommand", "EvaluateCells"} :> savePosition
        , PassEventsDown -> True
        }
      , CellEpilog :>  If[
          IntegerQ[cv]
        , SelectionMove[c, Before, CellContents]
        ; SelectionMove[nb, Next, Character, cv]
        ; cv = False
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

However, it made it so that when clicking <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to evaluate a cell, nothing happens. This issue only is on the notebook where this code was evaluated.

Unfortunately, refreshing the page, closing/reopening the tab, clicking “Reset to Default” in “Preferences” for “Evaluation”, and clicking “Evaluation” then “Restart Session” and “Quit Kernel” did not fix this issue. These steps usually reset presets for Wolfram Cloud, but not do so for this specific one.

The version is 14.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 13, 2023).

How does one make Wolfram Cloud be able to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and fix this glitch?

Comment: Basically, how does one undo the referenced code?

Comment: The code above can't work in the cloud because ``FrontEnd`UndocumentedGetSelectionPacket`` won't work there. And if you have problems with input cells in long notebooks without this code I suggest to contact Wolfram Support.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152178/discussion-between-tyma-gaidash-and-kuba).