# Setting Up Lightweight Grid On Multiple Clients Programmatically

Tags: parallelization, options, configuration

I have a number of computers which all might need to use the same (client) configuration for the Wolfram Lightweight Grid at some point.

I know that there are ways to programmatically set certain front-end options with commands akin to

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, RenderingOptions -> {"HardwareAntialiasingQuality" -> 1}]
```

as in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19440/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-set-global-preferences).

My question is: are there similar commands which, when I evaluate them on a given computer will set the Local->Lightweight Grid preference pane?  That is, I would love to have a notebook that I could distribute to my colleagues that contained code like

```
SetOptions[Something, LookForKernelsAt->IPAddress(es)OfTheComputer(s)RunningLightweightGrid]
```

that would configure their computers correctly and through Mathematica restarts (ie. so that they only have to evaluate the code one time).

Is this possible?  Do such commands exist?  I have been trying to understand what is provided in the `LightweightGridClient` and ``` Parallel``Developer ``` contexts but nothing seems to fit the bill.