# can one directly edit the custom dictionary?

Tags: notebooks, spellchecker

Apparently I mistakenly added a bad word to the custom spelling dictionary.

1. How can I remove the bad word?
2. Where is this dictionary stored?  I'd hope for it to be in a text file I could edit directly.

Comment: Can you check if there's anything in the folder returned by `FileNames[FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Autoload", "SystemFiles", "SpellingDictionaries"}]]`?

Comment: @J.M. Unfortunately, that returns an empty list.

Answer (score 4):

As shown [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/SpellCheckANotebook.html), you can edit your dictionaries in advanced options menu:

Edit -> Preferences... -> Advanced -> Open Option Inspector -> Formatting Options -> Text Content Options -> Spelling Dictionaries

Or you can set [SpellingDictionaries](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpellingDictionaries.html) option programmatically with [SetOptions[]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions.html) command, as shown in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19441/4863) answer.

Something like this should work:

```
file = Import["words.txt","List"]
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, SpellingDictionaries -> {"CorrectWords" -> file}]
```

P.S. Replace \$FrontEndSession with \$FrontEnd for a permanent global setting.

Comment: While the link you offer does *not* discuss removing words, the menu path you suggest does work.  The interface is slow and awkward, so I would like programmatic access.  I suppose I should be able to deduce this from the menu path, but I did not.  Can you add this to your answer?