# Export of 3D Plot

Tags: export

I finally got my 3D Graph :) Unfortunately, when I export I get a bad image quality.

[image: Exported PNG]

How can I export the image without the white stripes?

Here is the code for reproducing the error

```
scaleR = 1.2;
ni = 1;
no = 2;
IP = {3, 4, 4};

IncidentIn = {0, 1.5, 1.5};
IncidentOut = IP;
scale = Norm[IncidentOut - IncidentIn];
i = Normalize[IncidentOut - IncidentIn];
RadiusIn = IP;
n = Normalize[{0, 1, 1}];
t = Normalize[
ni/no i - n (ni/no (n.i) - Sqrt[1 - (ni/no)^2 (1 - (n.i)^2)])];
r = Normalize[i - 2 (n.i) n];
axial = {1, 0, 0};
cylinder = ContourPlot3D[
y^2 + z^2 == 32, {x, IncidentIn[[1]], (IP + scale r)[[1]]}, {y, -6,
6}, {z, -8, 8}, Mesh -> 1, 
ContourStyle -> FaceForm[{White, Red}, Opacity[0.0]], 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}];
cylinder2 = 
ContourPlot3D[y^2 + z^2 == 32, {x, IncidentIn[[1]], -(IP + scale r)[[1]]}, {y, -6, 6}, 
{z, -8, 8}, 
Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[1]], 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}];
areaR = ContourPlot3D[
axial.({x, y, z} - IncidentIn) == 0, {x, 
IncidentIn[[1]], (IP + scale r)[[1]]}, {y, -6, 8}, {z, -6, 8}, 
Mesh -> False];
planeOI = ContourPlot3D[Cross[r, t].({x, y, z} - IncidentIn) == 0, {x, 
IncidentIn[[1]], (IP + scale r)[[1]]}, {y, 0, Sqrt[64]}, {z, 0, 
Sqrt[64]}, ContourStyle -> {White, Opacity[1]}, Mesh -> False];
axial = Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[0.03], Black, Dashed, 
Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {(IP + scale r)[[1]] + 2, 0, 0}}], 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}}]; 
radius = Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[0.03], Black, Dashed, 
Arrow[{{3, 0, 0}, 1 + IP + scale n}], 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}}];
inv = Graphics3D[{Thick, Arrowheads[0.03], Darker[Red], 
Arrow[{IncidentIn, IP}], AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}}];
outv = Graphics3D[{Thick, Arrowheads[0.03], Darker[Blue], 
Arrow[{IP, IP + scale t}], AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}}];
reflv = Graphics3D[{Thick, Arrowheads[0.03], Darker[Green], 
Arrow[{IP, IP + scale r}], AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}}];
points = Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.008], Opacity[1], 
Point[{IncidentIn, IP, IncidentIn*{1, 0, 0} + IP*{0, 1, 1}, 
IP + scale t, IP + scale r }]}];
directCosinv = 
Graphics3D[{Darker[Red], Dashed, 
Line[{IncidentIn, (IncidentIn*{1, 1, 0} + 
IP*{0, 0, 1}), (IncidentIn*{1, 0, 0} + IP*{0, 1, 1}), IP}], 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}}];
directCosoutv = 
Graphics3D[{Darker[Blue], Dashed, 
Line[{IP, (IP*{1, 1, 0} + (IP + scale t)*{0, 0, 1}), (IP*{1, 0, 
      0} + (IP + scale t)*{0, 1, 1}), IP + scale t}], 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}}];
directCosreflv = 
Graphics3D[{Darker[Green], Dashed, 
Line[{IP, (IP*{0, 1, 1} + (IP + scale r)*{1, 0, 0}), (IP*{0, 0, 
1} + (IP + scale r)*{1, 1, 0}), IP + scale r}], 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}}];
plt = Show[points, planeOI, directCosreflv, directCosinv, 
directCosoutv, outv, areaR, reflv, inv, axial, radius, cylinder, 
cylinder2, Axes -> False, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Large, 
ViewPoint -> {1.388, -2.089, 2.27}, 
ViewVertical -> {-0.13, 0.09, 1}, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
Export["FresnelInVectors.png", plt, "PNG", ImageResolution -> 600]
```

Comment: You can try changing the `ContourStyle` in `cylinder` to `FaceForm[Red, Opacity[0.0]]`.  I cannot reproduce the problem on V9.0.1, V8.0.4 (Mac). If I turn on [`Antialiasing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Antialiasing.html), I get a totally black image, though.  Check whether yours is off, perhaps, change the setting.

Comment: @MichaelE2 [Mine's prettier](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yGHzE.png)! This is the recurring problem I have when I turn on Antialiasing ([details here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18996/crash-when-displaying-rasterizing-graphics-with-textures-at-high-resolutions))

Answer (score 2):

My OS is Mac OSX 10.7 or 10.8.
Switching Aliasing On or Off doesn't change things but when I reduce

```
ImageResolution -> 600
```

to

```
ImageResolution -> 500
```

the export works and the white stripes disappear. 
Using

```
ImageResolution -> 700
```

the white stripes appear again. So it seems reducing

```
ImageResolution
```

is the key!
Thanks for your fast answers

Comment: Just leaving a note to say that I came here today to ask about this issue. Thanks for answering my question before I asked it!